# why my pc is crashing when using da.where() and how to solve it?

Tags: python, dask

In order to broadcast 2d arrays and create a 3d array, i use this simple code.

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

x = da.random.uniform(size=(200, 100000), chunks=(200,100))
ind = da.random.binomial(1, 0.5, (200, 200, 1)).astype(np.bool)
x = da.where(ind, x, 0)
x = x.persist() #the crash happens here
print(x)`
```

I expect x to be a (200,200,100000) array with 0 where ind is False. However, its cause a sudden increase of the RAM usage and my pc freeze and it becomes unusable. I tried several chunk size but with the same result. 
setup:
os: linux mint 18
cpu: i5 4440
ram: 8gb
dask version: 1.2.0

thank you for your help

Comment: Do you know *which line* is causing the computer to crash? If not, can you go through it with a debugger real quick, put a breakpoint on each line, and figure it out?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash"? Do you get a segfault? A kernel panic? Something else?

Comment: I added more details in my post

Comment: if floats used are on 64 bits, you request (with persist) an object of 4gb in memory. It should fit in your 8, but it's sure is a lot!

Comment: Do you realize persist is quite the opposite of chunking? Form what I understood from the docs...